# Does the infinitive phrase in my example functions as an adjective or an adverb?

Tags: grammar, infinitives

**To keep the young recruits interested in getting in shape**, the coaching staff set up an exercise program for the summer months.

In the sentence, does the infinitive phrase "to keep the young recruits interested in getting in shape" function as an adjective or an adverb?

Answer (score 3):

It's an adverbial clause modifying "set up".

Adjectives describe nouns, and your bolded clause does not pertain to the coaching staff, to the exercise program, nor to the summer program. It tells us **why** the program was **set up**; therefore, it's an adverbial clause.